# Android sqlite application will not start and crashes immediately upon opening the app

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am currently working in eclipse with android adt and cannot get my application to open. I have tried cleaning the application and uninstalling it multiple times and I am not sure what else I can do to get my database to display the information. I am trying this on an emulator and on my motorola droid bionic android device. I am very new to programming in android so any type of help would be greatly appreciated and my code can be found below.  The specifics of the eclipse software are:

Eclipse SDK
Version: 4.2.1
Build id: M20120914-1800

Main activity where the database is created:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BloomBusiness";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Business";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "business text not null, address text not null, phone text not null, hours text not null" 
        + "website text not null)";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MainActivity(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Business");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public MainActivity open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String business, String address, String phone, String hours, String website) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEB, hours);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_BUSINESS,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_HOURS,
                KEY_WEB}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_BUSINESS, 
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_PHONE,
                        KEY_HOURS,
                        KEY_WEB
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String business, 
    String address, String phone, String hours, String website) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_HOURS,hours);
        args.put(KEY_WEB,website);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Database information being displayed:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBUse extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity db = new MainActivity(this);


        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{DisplayTitle(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
        db.open();
        Cursor b = db.getTitle(1);

        if (b.moveToFirst())
            DisplayTitle(c);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
    db.close();


}

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    }
```

Database information being added:

```
package com.example.database;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class DBActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity db= new MainActivity(this);

        db.open();
        long id;

        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","419 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-S:8AM-9PM Sun:9am-8PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop");
        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","316 W. 6th Street Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5300", "M-S:7AM-10PM Sun:9am-9PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop");
        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","3220 E. 3rd Street Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sun:8AM-10PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Uptown Cafe","102 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-0900", "M-S:8AM-9PM Sun:9am-8PM", "http://www.the-uptown.com/");



    }

}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.database"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.database.DBUse"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
04-15 20:50:23.122: E/Trace(638): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-15 20:50:24.062: E/SQLiteLog(638): (1) no such column: website
04-15 20:50:24.072: D/AndroidRuntime(638): Shutting down VM
04-15 20:50:24.072: W/dalvikvm(638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.DBUse}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: website (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, business, address, phone, hours, website FROM Business
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: website (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, business, address, phone, hours, website FROM Business
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.example.database.MainActivity.getAllTitles(MainActivity.java:101)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.example.database.DBUse.onCreate(DBUse.java:19)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-15 20:50:24.084: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to select a record with data in the "webiste" column, but your DATABASE_CREATE doesn't add this column.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: webiste (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, business, address, phone, hours, webiste FROM Business
```

Comment: After switching computers my emulator is now able to display the data. The only thing is is that nothing in my database is displayed except for "Hello World". I know that I have to change the XML layout in activity_main.xml but is there a suggestion as to which type I should use whether it be list or text?

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma between null and phone.

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "business text not null, address text not null, hours text not null," 
    + "phone text not null);";
```

Comment: Did you change the value of DATABASE_VERSION. If not DatabaseHelper:onUpgrade() will not run. If you don't want to change the database version number whatever device/emulator you're using will need to have the cache/data for your app cleared otherwise your application will continue to use the old Database you created earlier.

Comment: can you clean you project and rerun. TJ's solution should work based on the exception error message.

Comment: Are you saying that I need to change it to a value other than 1. It initially starts out at that and then further down in the code on the upgrade section it changes to the new version.

Comment: DATABASE_VERSION is final so it cannot be changed during runtime. It's used by the DatabaseHelper to figure out if the schema off the current database needs to be upgraded. If you haven't already try what Joseph suggested.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: Change the value of DATABASE_VERSION to 2 or completely remove your app from your testing device/emulator. Clean project then rebuild and run.

Comment: Can I email you the logcat I'm getting now after changing the DB from version 1 to 2?

Comment: @aNappyBoi Edit the question and add your new logcat at the bottom.

Comment: I've edited everything and included changes to MainActvity.java and the LogCat

Comment: @aNappyBoi If you read the logcat, you'll see that it's telling you that you're trying to select a column called 'website' which doesn't exist in the 'business' table. If you change your database scheme, either clear the app off your phone or change the value of DATABASE_VERSION. When you encounter an exception read the stack trace it will help you to figure out the problem. I'd say at this point your original issue has been resolved. You should close this question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; from your create table string and try. In my project I am not using ; at the end of the create statement.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "business text not null, address text not null, hours text not null," 
    + "phone text not null)";
```

I removed ; just after null) at end of the statement.

Comment: I made this change and there was still no new event in creating the database. The application still closes upon opening

Comment: The semicolon shouldn't have any impact in a create statement. All SQLite statements should be terminated with a semicolon otherwise the entire string is taken as a single statement. Since there are no other statements following the create table statement it makes no difference.